# What is this extra ServiceStack.Examples within ServiceStack.Examples?

Tags: servicestack

what is this?  After cloning ServiceStack.Examples from GitHub down to my local drive, I thought the root of ServiceStack.Examples was all it, meaning that was all the examples but then we have this repeated "ServiceStack.Examples" folder within the root also, can someone explain what is going on here?  It's not making any sense in terms of organization and what is what.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in this [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18954452/85785), **ServiceStack.Examples** was the first public example demo created for ServiceStack. Many years ago it was the only example in the project, we then started adding different standalone demos and so ServiceStack.Examples got pushed into its own folder.

Now instead of creating more stand-alone demos in SS.Examples we instead prefer to develop small, use-case focused examples as seen in [ServiceStack.UseCases](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.UseCases/).

Comment: I think it would be beneficial to state this then somewhere...new guys are diving in here wondering ok what is what, is this used anymore, etc.