# ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Examples is not RESTful?

Tags: servicestack

I'm struggling to see how this is RESTful.  I'm referring to the downloaded GitHub ServiceStack.Examples\src\ServiceStack.Examples\ServiceStack.Examples.sln.  I do not see anything restful about this, there is no RESTful routes here at all and the method names are all verbs but they're all like GEtThis, etc.  I don't see any Http verb attributes, nothing here.

Can someone explain what this is here becuase I feel like it doesn't even belong in the ServiceStack examples...??

[image]

Comment: if you examine the web page with the [examples](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.Hello/) you will see what example is REST, [here](http://www.servicestack.net/RestFiles/#!files) and [here](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStack.MovieRest/). The GetUsersService is the example with  [Ajax Client](http://www.servicestack.net/ServiceStackExamplesClients/)

Comment: Ok I just figured all of them would show REST examples being that this is the point of using the ServiceStack API!  ok thanks.  So I don't see the point of them putting non restful examples in here period IMO, it just promotes bad practice.

Comment: these are also RESTful https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/RedisStackOverflow and https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Examples/tree/master/src/RestIntro

Comment: ServiceStack is an awful lot more than just RESTful web services, it just makes them really easy to build.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Whilst SS allows you to implement REST services, it's not the only point of it. There's no such thing *best practices* for services, whether its SOAP, RPC, REST, message-based, HTTP, TCP, MQ, etc. Each have different strengths and tradeoffs that make it suitable for different domains. What matters is that the service is consumable + ideally interoperable, resilient, performant, versionable, etc. If you only want to do REST services, than stick to only studying and developing REST services. Having a preference does not give u the expertise to crucify the existence of other styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody said that example was supposed to be RESTful.

[ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) is a general **services framework** that lets you implement SOAP, MQ or REST+Web/HTML services with the same service.

The example your looking at is one of the first examples ever created for ServiceStack which makes use the **Old API**. You can compare and contrast it with the [New API here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api). Since the example implements `IService<T>` it's not a REST service, since every HTTP Verb will invoke the same implementation above. To provide different implementations for each verb with the Old API you would need to inherit `RestServiceBase<T>` instead, or preferably use the [New API](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api).

If you want to consume this service via [SOAP](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support) or [MQ hosts](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Messaging-and-Redis) than you need to ensure its accessible via **POST** by either maintaining single operation per Request DTO like this or by using a method named either `Post()` or `Any()` in the New API.

Comment: Here's the thing.  Every part of your "reason to use servicestack" talks about REST and how REST is the core reason to use this framework which is how it reads.  That's not my issue.  And you ARE preaching certain things such as why message based is the only way to go and I agree vs the others.  If you want your stack to seem less REST based then why is that the only thing your core intro docs always talk about?  That leads people to look for and thing that the sole goal here is REST

Comment: You also need to separate out the old from new, REST from non-REST, how are newbies who have never used this framework supposed to infer all you are saying even if we read the docs.  The examples part of the site gives barely any context and you have mixed old with new.  It would be helpful if you gave more info and split it out based on old and new vs dumping it all in examples.  Put in a folder called old and move the old examples there

Comment: Also i have been reading the docs and never have i seen a page like you replied with talking about the "New" API so where did you even stem that page from?  It's not in the right pane list on your wiki either...

Comment: @CoffeeAddict,   if you google "servicestack wiki" you will see the [New API](https://www.google.gr/search?q=servicestack+wiki&oq=servicestack+wiki&gs_l=serp.12..0l2j0i22i30l3.3713.4978.0.8027.5.5.0.0.0.0.112.519.2j3.5.0....0...1c.1.27.serp..0.5.519.1OwrUq_rK1I) . Or in [Getting Started 3.ServiceStack's new API Design](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/New-Api)   Also maybe your contributions to the open source and especially ServiceStack will be valuable, if you can help working on your proposals and upload your  results.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict Preaching a message-based style doesn't imply or mean "REST only", it's analog to REST. It actually requires extra effort to expose services under RESTful routes, as by default you can happily call services without any defining any custom routes (as the clients will fallback to the pre-defined routes). I don't want it to seem less REST or anything, SS is a versatile services stack that you can do and use the parts wish with. Research and explore only the features you prefer and find you're productive with.